# PFTableViewCell customising issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to display a class from Parse in a PFQueryTableViewController which works fine using the template file [found here on github](https://gist.github.com/ba03c1a550f14f88f95d) with the exception that I changed

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` to `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
```

This works fine as is; I can see the file (in this case an image) and text just fine, but the problem arises when I uncomment

```
-(PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
```

Here's the code I have (it's the same from the link above);

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];
    cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:self.imageKey];

    return cell;
}
```

When I uncomment that, I only get the `textLabel` display anything. The `imageView` doesn't load a thing - in fact, by adding in a `if (!cell.imageView)` I can see that the cell's imageView apparently doesn't exist...

I've made sure that my prototype cell in Storyboard has the CellIdentifier of `"Cell"` to match what is in the code, and of course my UITableViewController in Storyboard is of class `MyParseTableViewController` (which is a subclass of `PFQueryTableViewController`).

I'm at my wit's end...

I'm positive i've missed something, but I can't seem to find out what...

Any thoughts are welcome

Regards

/D

Comment: Is the cell in your storyboard a PFTableViewCell?

Comment: Yes it is. Can you replicate what I'm seeing at all?

Comment: Nope, sorry I don't use PFTableViewCells :( That was just one idea I had